# How to add jpg image as icon to root window in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using python 3 and tkinter. I want to place my own image as icon to root window in place of default tkinter icon. Please help me. I have tried this code but of no use.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Jun 21 10:12:56 2018

@author: Mahesh
"""
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import ttk
root=Tk()

root.title("Test Panel")
root.geometry('1100x800-120+0')

root.iconbitmap("C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Pythonmat\swam.jpg")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the image to `.ico`. The iconbitmap function does not support jpg.
You can alternetively use the `PIL` library to convert the image and then use it.

Comment: You can do that online. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only use ico files for this.

For example:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Pythonmat\py.ico')
root.mainloop()
```